# redirect on SimpleformController

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a `simpleformController` which needs to handle request get and post both. While gets the user needs to be redirected to login screen which works fine if `handlerequest` is used but `onSubmit` does not get called while posting the page?? Any idea why?

I have tried changing the `handlerequest` to a `private  void` method `displayForm` and called it from `formBackingObject` method which works fine while get and also calls the `onSubmit` method correctly as required.

But only problem is while calling `displayForm` a private void method I am unable to redirect the page to login as `formBackingObject` method does not have reponse object nor i can use return `ModelView` from `private` method `displayForm` as `formBackingObject` returns `Object`.

```
@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("In formBackingObject()... ");
  }
  Object obj = request.getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_FORM);
  if (obj != null) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()){
      logger.debug("update profile details form already exist, returning...");
    }
    return obj;
  }

  MyForm Form = new MyForm();

  request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_FORM, Form);

  displayForm(request);

  return Form;
}
```

Original method: does not allow post to be handle by `onSubmit`

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

  mv = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(request.getContextPath() + "login.htm"));

  RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
  requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);

  mv.addObject("c_name",getPManager().getCName());

  request.getSession().setAttribute("login_from_pac","yes");
  return mv;
}
```

New method: To load form, but user should be forced to login (redirected to login if login is correct user can see this form) before coming to this form. This method is called from `formBackingObject` method to load the form but does not have response object for redirection to login page. Following method does not work

```
private void displayForm(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

  HttpServletResponse response = null; -->
  ModelAndView mav = null;
  mav=new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(request.getContextPath() + "login.htm"));

  RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
  requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);

  //mav.addObject("c_name",getPManager().getCName());

  request.getSession().setAttribute("c_name", getPManager().getCName());

  request.getSession().setAttribute("login_from_pac","yes");
  //return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i could finally redirect to login page before reaching the main page call. I override isFormSubmission and used showForm instead of handlerequest or any private method called from formBackingObject. Heres the code

```
@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {           
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("In formBackingObject()... ");
        }
    Object obj = request.getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_FORM);
    if (obj != null) {
                    }
        return obj;
    }

    MyForm Form = new MyForm(); 

    request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_FORM, Form);


    return Form;
}

/**
 * Submit form
 * @param HttpServletRequest
 * @param HttpServletResponse
 * @param Object
 * @param BindException
 * @throws Exception 
 */
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()){
    logger.debug("onSubmit");
}



        ModelAndView mav;
        mav = new ModelAndView("formactivated");

        MyForm Form = (MyForm) command;


        try{                             
//do logic here

                                                    }

@Override
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)throws Exception {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("In showForm ... ");
    }

    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("In showForm  has errors... ");
        }
    ModelAndView mav;
    mav = new ModelAndView("formactivated");    
    mav.addAllObjects(errors.getModel());           
    return mav;
    }


    other login here
```

return successview
    }